# Why does module rec result in a warning?

Tags: f#

I am writing some JSON decoders for some types.

```ml
type FullName =
  {
    FirstName : string
    LastName : string
  }

type Person =
  {
    Name : FullName
    Role : string
  }
```

This code works fine:

```ml
module Thoth = 

  open Thoth.Json.Net

  [<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
  module FullName =

    let decode : Decoder<FullName> =
      Decode.object
        (fun get ->
          {
            FirstName = get.Required.Field "firstName" Decode.string
            LastName = get.Required.Field "lastName" Decode.string
          })

  [<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
  module Person =

    let decode : Decoder<Person> =
      Decode.object
        (fun get ->
          {
            Name = get.Required.Field "name" FullName.decode
            Role = get.Required.Field "role" Decode.string
          })
```

But suppose I want to take less care over the order of my declarations:

```ml
module rec Thoth =

  open Thoth.Json.Net

  [<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
  module Person =

    let decode : Decoder<Person> =
      Decode.object
        (fun get ->
          {
            Name = get.Required.Field "name" FullName.decode
            Role = get.Required.Field "role" Decode.string
          })

  [<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
  module FullName =

    let decode : Decoder<FullName> =
      Decode.object
        (fun get ->
          {
            FirstName = get.Required.Field "firstName" Decode.string
            LastName = get.Required.Field "lastName" Decode.string
          })
```

This code also works fine, but it gives a compiler warning:

> warning FS0040: This and other recursive references to the object(s) being defined will be checked for initialization-soundness at runtime through the use of a delayed reference. This is because you are defining one or more recursive objects, rather than recursive functions. This warning may be suppressed by using '#nowarn "40"' or '--nowarn:40'.

What are the consequences of suppressing this warning?

Short of going back to the first version, is there a way to use `module rec` that does not produce any warnings?

---

**Update!**

Curiously a `static member` works without warnings. Is this equivalent to the `module rec` approach above in terms of performance?

```ml
module rec Domain =

  open Thoth.Json.Net

  type Person =
    {
      Name : FullName
      Role : string
    }
    with
      static member Decode : Decoder<Person> =
        Decode.object
          (fun get ->
            {
              Name = get.Required.Field "name" FullName.Decode
              Role = get.Required.Field "role" Decode.string
            })

  type FullName =
    {
      FirstName : string
      LastName : string
    }
    with
      static member Decode : Decoder<FullName> =
        Decode.object
          (fun get ->
            {
              FirstName = get.Required.Field "firstName" Decode.string
              LastName = get.Required.Field "lastName" Decode.string
            })
```

Comment: The reason it works for static members is they are compiled as properties. It's actually `get_Decode ()` so it's a function rather than an object and the warning doesn't apply. What this does mean is the object will be recreated every time the property is called.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the compiler cannot reliably *prove* that `FullName.decode` will never be used before it's initialized, so instead it does two things:

1. Tells you about it, so you're aware.
2. Installs a runtime check to detect if it happens, and throws an exception when it does.

Looking at your code, it's pretty obvious to me that the value will never be used before initialization, even if the compiler can't prove it. So suppressing the warning should be fine.

However, you'll still be left with the runtime check, which will have some (though negligible) effect on performance.

Comment: That's disappointing, since there is an initialization order that would work, and it can be determined statically. Thanks!

Comment: @sdgfsdh Yes, it can be determined statically. I guess the point of not doing it is to discourage the use of `module rec` as a way to just reorder declarations that are not actually mutually recursive.